# javascript (angularjs) check if value exists in js object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have the following object

```
{
  0 : false,
  1 : true,
  2 : false
}
```

What i need to do is i loop through these and set some of them to true or false depending on the condition but i need a function to check if all values are set to true or if false exists in the object.

I have the following to check if the value is false to do something

```
 angular.forEach($scope.keyFiles, function (val, key) {
        if(val == false) {
              $scope.loadCanvas(key);
              return key;
        }
 });
```

but i need something now to check if false exists at all in any of the values and if all values are set to true.

Im new to javascript so excuse me if this sounds like a simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
function containsFalse(obj){
    for(var prop in obj){
       if(obj[prop] === false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This actually just check one value at a time to see if its false or true. What will happen with this is if the first value is true and the rest is false then its going to assume everything is true

Comment: @Yeak that's not a true. Do a dry run with the above code. The method returns `true` when it first encounters `false` as value of a property. If no such property exists it returns `false` which is what has been asked for

Comment: No. this loops through every property of the object and checks if it is false. if not, it will continue to the next property. If none is found at end of the iteration, returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plain javascript way of doing it:

```
var keyFiles = {
  0 : false,
  1 : true,
  2 : false
};

var falseExists = false;
for (var prop in keyFiles) {
    if (keyFiles.hasOwnProperty(prop) && keyFiles[prop] === false) {
        falseExists = true;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(falseExists);
```

More on `hasOwnProperty` in this [**MDN link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

In modern browsers (i.e, IE 9+, Chrome 5+ etc) the code can be simplified as below:

```
for (var prop in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(keyFiles)) {
    if (keyFiles[prop] === false) {
        falseExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```